Puzzle Relating to Colors
This puzzle originates from a puzzle posted on the DECIPHER discord server as a fun challenge, but I can't seem to get how this puzzle works.
We are given the colors (hex):

#763939
#121847
#381286

and the quotes



"Color! what a deep and mysterious language, the language of dreams." - Paul Gaugin




"The whole is greater than the sum of its parts" - Aristotle




Thats interesting. ill look into that

I realized i messed up the colors. they are fixed now
